# How can I get show the remaining date in a good format?

Tags: php

I am creating a value that shows me the remaining time from a date until now:

```
$date=date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($mydate)));
$curdate=date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$diff=date_diff($date,$curdate);
$diff1= $diff->format("%y years %m months %d days");
```

The result in this case is: `0 years 0 months 27 days`

What I would like to do is, show only `years` or `months` if they are not `0`. So in this case I would only like to get the result `27 days`. And if it is only one day left, then it shows `1 days` but it should show `1 day` (so if the result is `1` show singular).

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
$diff1= $diff->format(if("%y" !=0){"%y years"}); if("%m" !=0){"%m months"}) %d days");
```

Comment: May be checkout **util.php** class on *github*, it has a function named `human_time_diff`. You can find the class here: https://github.com/brandonwamboldt/utilphp

Comment: There is no **magic bullet** you just have to write some tests to decide what to output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) returns an instance of the [DateInterval class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) which has the class variables `$y`, `$m` and `$d` for the corresponding years, months and days.

As such what you were trying to achieve can still be done using these variables:

```
$diff=date_diff($date,$curdate);
$format = '';
if ($diff->y > 0) {
     $format = '%y years';
} else if ($diff->m > 0) {
     $format = '%m months';
} else {
     $format = '%d days';
}
$diff1 = $diff->format($format);
```

The elimination of the s in years/months/days is left up to the OP.

(edited)

In this case only one category will printed, but to get more than one at a time, modify the 'if-else' to individual 'if' and concatenation with previous categories,

```
if ($diff->y > 0) {
     $format = '%y years ';
}
if ($diff->m > 0) {
     $format .= '%m months ';
}
if ($diff->d > 0) {
     $format .= '%d days';
}
```

Comment: I tried your code with `$date=2015-05-14 16:43:31`. The result is `8 months`. But the result I need in this case is: `8 months 3 days`

Answer (score 1):

### Powerful Function to get two date difference.

PARA: *Date Should In YYYY-MM-DD Format*

**RESULT FORMAT:**
// '%y Year %m Month %d Day %h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds'        =>  1 Year 3 Month 14 Day 11 Hours 49 Minute 36 Seconds

// '%y Year %m Month %d Day'                                    =>  1 Year 3 Month 14 Days

// '%m Month %d Day'                                            =>  3 Month 14 Day

// '%d Day %h Hours'                                            =>  14 Day 11 Hours

// '%d Day'                                                        =>  14 Days

// '%h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds'                                =>  11 Hours 49 Minute 36 Seconds

// '%i Minute %s Seconds'                                        =>  49 Minute 36 Seconds

// '%h Hours                                                    =>  11 Hours

// '%a Days                                                        =>  468 Days

```
function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat = '%a' ){
$datetime1 = date_create($date_1);

$datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

return $interval->format($differenceFormat);}
```

Follow this link
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php